# How to send a http request using spray

Tags: scala, spray

I'm building just off the spray.io github project, and I have the default page working, and I've been able to add more pages with html. However, I want to be able to have the pages interact in some way (get information from each other). Right now, I want to at least return the code posted on a page, which I think is the simplest thing to do as a first step.

This is my code:

```
trait MyService extends HttpService {
val Route = 
path("one") {
  get {
    respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
      complete {
        <html>
          <body>
            SOME HTML
          </body>
        </html>
         }
        }
      }
    } ~ 
path("test"){
        get {
           //return data from path /one
        }
    }
}
```

what would I put in the get method of test so that it asks for data from the "one" page?

Thanks!

Comment: the simplest option seems to be using redirect http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/html-redirect.htm, or any JavaScript instruments for that. You can also obtain it on server-side using java-http api.

Comment: In SO, thanks are usually in the form of accepted answer which you don't seem to do. Anyways, If you are using spray framework, then you will have to use spray-client(http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-M8/spray-client/) to make the request and get the response as Future.